# How to start X program on local display?

Tags: linux, xorg, x11, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm ssh-ing into a Raspberry Pi. I would like to start an X program remotely, on the Pi's display.

I know you can `export DISPLAY` to have programs open up on your computer when you ssh-in. But I'm looking for the opposite.

What I'd like to have is have a program open up on the Pi's own (HDMI connected) display, when I run a command from ssh.

What I'm looking for is to have a program run on the Pi and display it on the Pi. Pretty much I'd like to just remote control the Pi, using my desktop's keyboard.

I'm on Raspbian / Deb Wheezy.

Comment: That should be the default behavior unless you are using the `-X` or `-Y` options to ssh in. Doesn't it work? Do you get an error?

Comment: Yes, my error is like `Error: Can't open display: (null)
Failed creating new xdo instance`. I'm just using normal ssh to log-in, not -X or -Y

Comment: You need to set `DISPLAY=:0` and to configure `xauth`.

Answer (score 1):

Just run xeyes on the PI (check that you have env variable DISPLAY setup `export DISPLAY=:0.0` or specify it directly

`xeyes -display ':0.0'`

Comment: I guess this runs a program on my desktop and displays it on the Pi. What I'm looking for is to have a program run on the Pi and display it on the Pi.
Pretty much I'd like to just remote control the Pi, using my desktop's keyboard.

Comment: Arh sorry, misunderstood, when you said opposite. Just run xeyes on the PI (check that you have env variable DISPLAY setup `export DISPLAY=:0.0`